# Creating Grid on the fly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, frontend

I'm new to frontend and I'm trying to practice doing this simple task: I have to create a grid on the fly that is n * n (n being inputed by the user).

I succesfully created a fix sized grid, but my problem is when trying to do this dynamically.

This is the code I wrote for a 3*3 grid: http://jsfiddle.net/y7c2h8yk/

For trying to create it dynamically I wrote the following function:

```
var setGridDimensions = function(n) {
    // emptying current grid
    $(".row").empty();
    var $grid = $("#grid");
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // adding row
        $grid.append('<div class="row">');
        // adding each to element to row
        **var $row = $(".row")[i];**
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            $row.append('<div class="col"></div>');
        }
    }
};
```

Now, I understand there is a problem with line `var $row = $(".row")[i]`. What I need is inside the loop first create the row, then select the row created and then loop again and create each column. How can i do that ?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to force jQuery to search for the `.row` element in the DOM tree `n` times. You have easy way to *cache* the element by setting it as variable.

Another thing, is that you should `empty()` the whole `#grid` element instead of `.row`. **`empty()`** method remove contents of the element, but not the element itself.

Alternatively, you could remove rows using `$(".row").remove();`

- [`.empty()` reference](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)
- [`.remove()` reference](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

---

Code (I would however use the next one)

```
var setGridDimensions = function(n) {
    var $grid = $("#grid").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // create .row and cache it setting as '$row' variable:
        var $row = $('<div class="row"/>').appendTo($grid);
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            $row.append('<div class="col"></div>');
        }
    }
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zzkz3Lvc/)

This would be faster than the one above, as it's single DOM modification:

```
var setGridDimensions = function(n) {
    var html ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        html += '<div class="row">';
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            html += '<div class="col"></div>';
        }
        html += '</div>';
    }
    // modify the DOM only once:
    $("#grid").html(html);
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/asaoq30v/)

Comment: Thanks ! I thought that emptying the grid was going to remove the grid div and I wasn't going to be able to append rows to it, but it also works.

Comment: This only empty the element. For removing elements is  `.remove()` method  - updated answer

Answer (score 1):

`$(".row")[i]` get the HTML element. So late, the `$row.append('<div class="col"></div>');` will not work since `.append()` is a jQuery method.

If you want to select a specific index and keep it as a jQuery object, use `.eq()` :

```
var $row = $(".row").eq(i);
for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    $row.append('<div class="col"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/evxqybaL/1/

```
<div id="grid-holder"></div>
```

-

```
#grid-holder {
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    clear: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.cell {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    float: left;
}
```

-

```
var gridly = function (n) {
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid-holder");
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.classList.add("row");
        grid.appendChild(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.classList.add("cell");
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }             
}

gridly(5);
```

Comment: Sorry for the purely JavaScript function; I somehow missed that you were asking how to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

use isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ it uses the help of Javascript but it is very popular, so you will find plenty of docs

if you find it very complicated then there are many premium plugins that based their development on isotope already, for example the Media Boxes http://codecanyon.net/item/media-boxes-responsive-jquery-grid/5683020